# Crawling the WP8 Store

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8

Last year I wrote a CMS for a client that allowed them to search the Windows Phone Marketplace for WP 7.5 apps and add them to a list for an app they have. To accomplish the search, I was using the Zest XML feed to get the search data back.

For example:

```
http://catalog.zune.net/v3.2/en-US/apps?q=Spotify&clientType=WinMobile%207.1&store=zest
```

Calling the above would return an XML response that my code would parse to display the results in the CMS.

This has all worked fine, but now that Windows Phone 8 is out, I am having to update my CMS to allow our client to search for WP8 apps. The problem is I can't simply change the clientType in the URL above to WinMobile 8.0. Doing so returns no results no matter what. I also can't leave off the clientType parameter because that causes it to throw an error.

**So my question is: Is it possible to search the Windows Phone Store for WP8 apps using the above method?**

Since Windows Phone 8 is so new, I'm not having much luck finding any info on doing this for 8.0 apps. Plenty for 7 and 7.5. It's entirely possible that the Zest feed simply doesn't support 8.0 queries yet, but I'm hoping someone out there knows a way to do it.

It's not an option to leave it as-is (searching only for WP 7.5 apps) because there are some apps that are only available for 7.5 and not 8 or vice-versa. For example, Spotify comes up if you search for 7.5 apps (from the example URL above), but does not come up if you search for 8.0 apps (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/search?q=spotify).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Whats about parsing plain HTML and extracting the information you need?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy, just install the WP8 SDK, start the emulator and also start some kind of network sniffer like Fiddler.
Then browse the Windows Phone Store in the emulator and the sniffer should capture all requests, including addresses you are looking for, unless of course encryption or SSL is now used on WP8 for browsing the Windows Phone Store.

Comment: Is the store available on the emulator images for 8? I know it isn't for 7.5 (and not having a processor that supports SLAT, I'd have to go buy a new PC to check)

Comment: Yes, there is Windows Phone Store browser in WP8 emulator, you just can't install any app.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Not having much luck with Fiddler as it seems to be blocking network calls from the emulator. I'll keep trying though.